How to standardize a correlation from a bariogram, to force bounds between -1 and 1
Context: I have 2 1D vectors of 1000 values: one of them represents represents a variable (vector d), the other (vector dates) represents the temporal coordinates of each entry of d. I want to calculate the correlogram of this dataset.
Steps:

I detrend d from its mean: d_m = d - mean(d)
I calculate the Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) of d_m: MAD = median(abs(d_m - median(d_m))
I standardize d_m by the MAD: sd_m = d_m/MAD
I compute the variogram (variogram) of sd_m, the coordinates are the entries of the vector dates
I compute the correlogramof sd_m: correlogram = (variance(sd_m) - variogram) / variance(sd_m)

Problem: Although I standardize the dataset, the correlogram is not bounded between -1 and 1. I chose the MAD approach because the variogram makes it difficult to determine the variance graphically or by taking the average value of the furthest point of the variogram. I tried filtering my dataset (by removing any value with its absolute 4 times above the MAD) but there are still a fair amount of outliers.
Question: How can I compute a correlation, from a variogram, and standardize it to be between -1 and 1 ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
